# What does 時間が惜しい。この部屋も掃除させてもらうぞ mean?

Tags: translation

What i got from this is : "it's bad timing i will have to clean this room too." Am i close?

Answer (score 5):

> 「時間{じかん}が惜{お}しい。この部屋{へや}も掃除{そうじ}させてもらうぞ。」

Without further context, it is rather difficult to tell exactly how the two sentences could connect.

I, however, could not think of a situation where 「時間が惜しい」 could mean "It is bad timing." It should mean along the lines of "***Time is too precious to lose***." pretty much every time we say it.

The second sentence means "***I'll take the liberty of cleaning up this room as well***."

It sounds as if the speaker were in a hurry and having to clean up a couple of rooms as quickly as possible.